# How can I make a proper RPG levelling system?

Tags: math, system

So basically I'm making a JRPG, and I'm trying to determine the level of a Fighter by how much XP it has.

So if my Fighter has 0 XP, it's going to be a level 1, but if it has say 1000 XP, it'll be a level 2.

I want the amount of XP required to make a level to go up as the Fighter levels up, so something like 1000 XP to get to lvl 1, and 1400 to get to lvl 2 (maybe not so drastic, but I think you get the picture).

**I need a formula that determines the level using only the given XP value.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use some variation of the sum of n natual numbers (http://www.9math.com/book/sum-first-n-natural-numbers) in order to calculate how much XP you need to reach a level.  Once you've done that you'll need to use a loop to count up from 0 or 1 depending on your starting level and check to see if the f(n) > current xp, then return n-1.

I'd make a function to calculate the XP needed for a given level n so that if you need to tweak it you only need to change it in one place.